# React + React-router -> Child routes best organization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a conceptual problem concerning my authentification pages.

Currently i have this  :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

Now i would like to wrap all my 'Auth page' in a parent container 'Auth' so i do this :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="/auth" component={Auth}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

The problem : Now if i would like to access to my login page i would go to

> /auth/login

But i need my login page stay on

> /login

What is the best pratice to do this ?

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found a solution who work fine

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="/" component={Auth}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" component={About} />

  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: You can also just omit the path="/" from the second Route element.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's intended more for backwards comparability, you can just use the react-router's [`Redirect`](http://%3CRedirect%20from=%22profile/:userId%22%20to=%22about/:userId%22%20/%3E) component:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="/auth" component={Auth}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
  </Route>

  <Redirect from="/login" to="/auth/login" />

  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: With Redirect component the final routes is /auth/login but i need /login

Comment: Why should the final route matter?

Comment: The final route should be /login :)

Comment: A noble cause indeed :)